Can I say "That museum was a hit back then"?
The definition of "a hit" in the dictionary is a person or thing that is very popular. But when I read the example sentences, it was mostly used for films, music, stars,...
So I'm wondering if we can use "a hit" for other things like places, ...

Films, pop songs etc. are usually 'a hit' for a short time after they are first released. So you could use the expression metaphorically to indicate that a new museum was extremely popular for a time when it first opened.

'Hit' is quite an informal word; 'great success' might be better for formal writing.

What @KateBunting said. I think describing anything as "permanent, enduring, long-lived" as a museum would always be at least somewhat facetious. But that's because museums are inherently expected to last for at least decades (hopefully centuries), not because it's a place. Woodstock was unquestionably a hit with American youth in the late 60s - that was a place, but its astonishing popularity as a venue only lasted a matter of days.

If the New York Times can say (in an informally-toned article): "the museum was a hit from the day it opened in 2004" then I don't see why not. (NB: I found this by googling "museum was a hit" in quotes.)

Yes, anything can be 'a hit' if it's very popular, well liked, or well received for a period of time. Your example of the museum works well. Here are some other examples with context:

A: Will you be bringing a dessert to the party tomorrow?
B: Absolutely! I have to make my grandmother's chocolate cake recipe again - it was such a hit last time.


I was worried about choosing a nontraditional wedding dress when I decided on wearing green instead of white. It turns out that I shouldn't have worried, it was a hit! I had three cousins ask where I got it for their own weddings.


When we have quiet days at work, I like to bring my dog with me. She's a hit - my coworkers all love her!

As Michael mentioned in the comments, this is a slang term and is informal. If you are writing or speaking formally, "great success" or "was well received" are better options.
